# Is it possible to track pages in groups dynamically?

Tags: google-analytics

I have organized pages on my site in groups and can determine this "group" name dynamically on any page it the page belongs to a group.

groups could be:

```
frontpage
category-technology
category-conceptcars
category-somethingelse
loginpage
```

while frontpage group may only have one page, a category group could have 3 or more. I'd like to have statistics per group (mainly hits per month) and am wondering if i can track these in google analytics somehow with the dynamic group name.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can track these with [page scoped custom vars](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setCustomVar).

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-12345678-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'page-group', 'frontpage', 3]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

Comment: And I will be able to retrieve the statistics for this custom var later in analytics?

Comment: Sure you can see them in the custom var report. They live in AUDIENCE>Demographics>Custom Var.